# Autoware - can't launch .launch file without runtime manager

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Autoware Docker pre-built container `autoware/autoware:latest-melodic-cuda`
- Local ROS version: Kinetic

Hi all,

I'm trying to use most of Autoware's packages  without launching them from the runtime manager.
I use a .launch file that launches all the packages and nodes I need. This works fine, except for `ndt_matching.launch` from the `lidar_localizer` package.
I realized that even by running:

`cd /home/autoware/Autoware`

`source install/setup.bash`

`roslaunch lidar_localizer ndt_matching.launch`

I get the following error:

> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid
> [12645]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> setting /run_id to
> 5739dd7a-1c64-11ea-8d07-48a472bde50c
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid
> [12656] started core service [/rosout]
> process[ndt_matching-2]: started with
> pid [12659] terminate called after
> throwing an instance of
> 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error
>
> > '   what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid
> > argument [ndt_matching-2] process has
> > died [pid 12659, exit code -6, cmd
> > /home/autoware/Autoware/install/lidar_localizer/lib/lidar_localizer/ndt_matching
> > __name:=ndt_matching __log:=/root/.ros/log/5739dd7a-1c64-11ea-8d07-48a472bde50c/ndt_matching-2.log].
> > log file:
> > /root/.ros/log/5739dd7a-1c64-11ea-8d07-48a472bde50c/ndt_matching-2*.log

Any idea why? I realized that this doesn't happen when I first launch the runtime manager and then kill the runtime manager's node from the command line and eventually launch ndt_matching.launch. This must be something configured when launching `roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch`.

By the way, by default the ndt_matching method used is `pcl_generic`, and not `pcl_anh` or other, which I have read had some issues in the past with the same kind of error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339748/autoware---can%27t-launch-.launch-file-without-runtime-manager/) by [Doug](https://answers.ros.org/users/45207/doug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Doug have a look [here](https://www.96boards.org/blog/autoware.ai_hikey970/) it outlines how to launch the rosbag demo headless, in particular you might be missing some parameters that are loaded when the runtime manager starts, the post shows how to get them

---

Originally posted by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) with karma: 166 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Doug](https://answers.ros.org/users/45207/doug/) on 2019-12-12**:
Thanks ! That was it. I needed to do:
`rosparam load headless_setup.yaml`

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2021-07-07**:
@sgermanserrano I'm trying to follow the guide, but I'm unable to download some of the files (headless_setup.yaml), as they seems they are not available anymore.

Would you be so kind of uploading them again, please?

Thank you.